# Update and replace unquoted JSON strings

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-5.7

I have the following table in my database:

```
              Type | Name
-------------------------------------------------
  INT(10) UNSIGNED | id
          LONGTEXT | settings
```

The settings column holds JSON strings such as the following:

```
'[
    {"value":"1","label":"user_type"},
    {"value":"2","label":"email_type"}
]'
```

I have some corrupt data that doesn't correspond to the required format as the requirements have now changed.

```
'[
    {"value": 8,"label":"should_receive_notifications"},
]'
```

Notice how the value is unquoted compared to the first example which is how I need them.

Is there a way I can do a find and replace on all JSON strings within the settings column to update all unquoted values in the JSON string and wrap them in quotes?

Comment: Show the output for `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: Version is 5.7.37

Comment: My initial idea is to use something such as JSON_extract and do something like the following:

SELECT json_extract(settings, '$[*].value') FROM table;

Comment: Does the structure of JSON matches shown example value completely? Does `"value"` is the only property needed in such quoting?

Comment: Yes, it's just the 'value' property that needs its assigned value in quotes. These are always IDs, so i'd like to wrap them all in quotes.

Comment: And why you use LONGTEXT and not JSON datatype? MySQL 5.7 supports it...

Comment: Not 100% sure, this is an adopted project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the next procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE quote_value(max_amount INT)
BEGIN
REPEAT
    UPDATE test
    SET settings = JSON_REPLACE(settings, CONCAT('$[', max_amount, '].value'), CAST(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(settings, CONCAT('$[', max_amount, '].value'))) AS CHAR));
    SET max_amount = max_amount - 1;
UNTIL max_amount < 0 END REPEAT;
END
```

`max_amount` parameter defines the amount of objects in the array to be updated (do not forget that the array elements are counted from zero). So set it to max objects per array amount value.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=166f43d44e57b62da034bd9530713beb

Comment: Is there a way i can allow the procedure to accept other parameters such as table name and column name if i want to make it more flexible. Or would i need to wrap it in a variable and turn it into a prepared statement?

Comment: @Dmc If you need to parametrize objects names than dynamic SQL is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

This is under assumption that there are no spaces between  the characters in json string, simple but data needs to be verified for this.

```
update tablename
set settings = replace(settings, '"value\":' , '"value":\"')
where settings not like '%"value":"%'

update tablename 
set settings = replace(settings, ',"' , '","')
where settings not like '%","%'
```